# asp.net core 3.0 Signal R instantly disconnects

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

i am working on an asp.net core project that depends on Signal R.
I updated the project from dotnet core 2.2 to 3.0.
With dotnet 2.2 everything worked but with 3.0 when the Client connects to Signal R the Connection is closed instantly without any error.
I searched in the documentation from Microsoft but found nothing. What did i miss?

#### DevTools Console:

```
Start connection
[2019-11-22T12:28:11.744Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5000/game
[2019-11-22T12:28:11.745Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.
[2019-11-22T12:28:12.073Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
Connection Lost
```

#### Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<GameManager>();
        services.AddSingleton<UserRepository>();

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Spa:Root");
        });

        services.AddSignalR(configur =>
        {
            configur.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        }).AddJsonProtocol();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<GameHub>("/game");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000/");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Client:

```
    this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`http://localhost:5000/game`, HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
        .withHubProtocol(new JsonHubProtocol())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start to debug this by making the connection as simple as possible.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/game").build();
```

Comment: I have tried this but the connection still closes immediately

Comment: Also you can reduce it in StartUp.cs to `Services.AddSignalR();`. And share GameHub.cs with us.